# Centre Text and Form (Email Input and Submit button) Over a Centred Image

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to center some text and a form (text input and submit button) over an image that is already centered.

My HTML/CSS has the three items centered but one after the other i.e. the image is centered, the text is centered below it and my input form is below that.

Can you let me know how I can center my text and form over a image that is centered. The over goal is to have the three items stay centered together if the browser window's size  is changed.

NOTE: I have other images and text above the three items that I am trying to center

My HTML is as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="banner.png" alt="banner" height="250" width="900" />
    </div>

    <p class="textbox">
    some text. some text.some text.some text.some text.some text.some text.some text.some text.
    </p>

    <--Below is the HTML for the centering of the three items. They are centered sequentally NOT on top of the image.

    <div class="formoutline">
        <img src="formboxdark.png" alt="formbox" height="160" width="350" />
    </div>

    <div class="signupnote">
        </p>please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.</p>
    </div>

    <div class=formlocation>
        <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="user" class="emailfield" value="email@example.com" />
            <input type="submit" class="submitbutton" value="Submit" />
        </form>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
 body
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background:url(texture.jpg);
    }
    .banner
    {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
    .textbox
    {
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    }

    /*This is where the CSS for the three items (image, text and form) begins*/

    .formoutline
    {
    text-align:center;
    top:330px;
    left:485px;
    }
    .signupnote
    {
    text-align: center;
    color:#225DCE;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    }
    .formlocation
    {
    text-align:center;
    }
    .emailfield
    {
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
    width:200px;
    }
    .submitbutton
    {
    height:28px;
    width:70px;
    }
```

If you need any further details please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content that you want to center together should all be in one div tag, not 3 seprate one as you have there:

```
<--Below is the HTML for the centering of the three items. They are centered 
sequentally NOT on top of the image.

<div class="style for single containing div">

</p>please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please  
sign up.please sign up.please sign up.please sign up.</p>

<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="user" class="emailfield" value="email@example.com" />
        <input type="submit" class="submitbutton" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Style for that div:

```
.style for single containing div
{
margin: 0 auto; (this will center your div absolutely, even when resizing your window)
background-image: url('formboxdark.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
height: 160px; 
width: 350px; 
text-align: center;
}
```

Try that and let me know

Comment: Superb. It works like a charm. Thank you so much. I was at my wits end. One last tweak...Is there a way to have the test centered AND justified?

Comment: That justifies the text, but unfortunately causes the input fields to be moved left to the edge of the image. I found the following on stackoverflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704896/how-can-i-do-center-justified-text).Any idea how to incorporate it? I will look into it also. Your input would be valuable.

Comment: Just add: text-align: justify;

Comment: Just add inline styling to your form tag: 
style="text-align: center;" Just add this in your form tag.

Comment: I am indebted to you. What I have been struggling with for a day and a half you have solved in a few minutes. Thank you so much.