# How do I center AND justify text, like in this image?

Tags: css, image, alignment, center, justify

I've taken a look at the other questions, but they're all about centering a blog of left aligned justified text. What I'm struggling with is to center the text and also justify it in a given width.

[image: The image below is a crop of what I designed in Photoshop, I hope to code something like this]

This is my current block of CSS code:

```
#body-container .intro p {
    top: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Any suggestions, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Is the paragraph tag picking up any other styles? http://jsfiddle.net/FuvHt/ Seems to work

Comment: Nope, it doesn't seem to work @WoolyWonder. He is asking for justify+center, not just justify.

Comment: @WoolyWonder Take a look at the image once again, what it does is, it centers even the extra in-justified sentences (in your fiddle, it's the word 'width'). And no, I've pointed the css to the specific 'p' tag, so I don't think anything else will get picked up.

Comment: @TheBronx exactly. I've scoured Google too, no luck in the first 3 pages. Maybe beyond? Or maybe not possible for now?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704896/how-can-i-do-center-justified-text and see the second answer. Looks promising

Comment: @TheBronx Of course, I checked SO first :) But no luck there too, tried incorporating the first two answers, both of them just justified the text, but didn't center the extra text.

Comment: LOL, its true, it doesn't work. Why the upvotes then? xD Sorry!

Comment: @TheBronx Even I was curious :P I guess a lot of people wanted just justify, but not justify + center. It was so easy to mock it up on Photoshop, why so much trouble in CSS? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a real solution, as it seems this is experimental and only works in firefox and explorer:

```
-moz-text-align-last: center;
text-align-last: center;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/text-align-last

Comment: Just checked, it does work. Problem is, I normally use Google Chrome, wonder what kind of fallback I can use for that. Anyways, thank you for the temporary solution, it's the best option for now. Please let me know if you find a way to center+justify, thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Well, you can use Firefox :P or Explorer as it also supports it hehe. Ask chrome dev team to implement it: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76173

Comment: Wow, surprising. Works in IE but not in Chrome. And it's supposed to be like the 'People's Browser' :P Anyways, I might just have to, but reading the comments, I'm just baffled :P I thought it was much easier to include a style in a browser, guess I was wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for misunderstanding the question in the comments.

Is the content of the paragraph dynamic, or is it fixed?

If it's fixed, you could wrap the last line in a span tag.

```
span {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}
```

I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FuvHt/7

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it's going to be dynamic. Since I've kept everything responsive, the last line will change according to the screen size. But thank you for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to do it right now is to cut the text out as an image.

If your site isn't responsive you can throw a `<br />` tag in there, wrap a `<span>` on the last line, and then center align that text.

I'm really looking forward to the `text-align-last` css property becoming more widely adopted.