# How to Center-Justify links in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I center-justify a list of links in CSS?

This is similar to this question: [How to Center-Justify text in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704896/how-to-center-justify-text-in-css), except using links instead of text. The fiddle from that answer there (http://jsfiddle.net/L4pzm/) doesn't work when I use links instead of text.

This is how they did it in the above fiddle:

```
.center-justified {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: justify;
width: 30em;
}
```

Here is the fiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/hsm4w0p5/

```
<div class="center-justified"><p>
<a href="1">First </a><a href="2">Second</a><br>
<a href="3">Third <a href="4">Fourth </a><a href="5">Fifth</a></p>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example above, the links aren't justified. I want to make it so that the word "Second" is aligned to the right to match with the word "Fifth".

Comment: i personally have never seen CSS do that before :/ interesting question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using text-align: justify, but can use flexbox to do something similar:

Html:

```
<div class="center-justified">
    <div class="row">
        <a href="1">First </a><a href="2">Second</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <a href="3">Third <a href="4">Fourth </a><a href="5">Fifth</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center-justified {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30em;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/czcegf2d/1/

Be sure to check the browser compatibility of flexbox (which is quite good these days) and see that it fits your needs. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Thanks! This ended up doing what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to be dynamic you could target each link with the [:nth-child(n) CSS selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) to float left and right inside the .center-justified container.

like:

```
.center-justified a:nth-child(2n) {float:right}
```