# Is there any CSS tag to justify content (like in word)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want ***National and International brands*** to be placed in the center under the above present text.

OutPut:

[image]

The CSS code-

```
.ans{
    padding-top: 1.2vh;
    display:flex;
    color:lightsalmon;
    font-size: 5vh;
    text-justify: auto;

}
```

The HTML Code-

```
<div id="qa">
    <p class="q">
        Why HOTPICKS?
    </p>
    <p class="ans">
        HOTPICKS provides a discount of Upto 75% on National and International Brands. 
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `justify-content: center`

Comment: Put those two words in their own element which you give CSS text-align: center

Comment: Beyond the normal "google for how to center text using CSS", also give https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox a (re)read-through, which covers all the "Word-like" layout control for both horizontal and vertical alignment and justification with plenty of copy-pastable examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4704896/4356188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: avoiding `text-align-last: center;` due low support. (https://caniuse.com/css-text-align-last)

The problem is how to center a specific line of a text or how to wrap exactly. If it's critical what I'd probably do while researching a solution would be wrap the line in a span tag with display: block but remove this display: block in low resolutions (using @media queries).

See the next snippet (without the @media to see a break problem in low res)

```css
.ans{
    padding-top: 1.2vh;
    color:lightsalmon;
    font-size: 5vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.ans span {
    display: block;
}

.q {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="qa">
    <p class="q">
        Why HOTPICKS?
    </p>
    <p class="ans">
        HOTPICKS provides a discount of Upto 75% on 
        <span>National and International Brands.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

This works but the break could be weird with little width resolution, that's why I recommend disable on mobile.

This means modify html but I prefer that to superhacky css weird tricks using margins. Matter of personal preferences.

Comment: it doesn’t work. I’m in mobile Safari.

Comment: @clickbait rly? text-align is a very basic standard CSS property. I just tried with Safari on mobile too and works. So weird.

Comment: the OP asks how to center the last line in `.ans`

Comment: @clickbait My fault, I just focused on the image and thought he wants to center the title. I've updated my answer with a flex version centering both but keeping the text justified to the left. Ty.

Comment: Still doesn’t seem to work. I think the OP wants the `.ans` text to be justified with its last line centered.

Comment: @clickbait I know I know, I'm working on it =P seems hard without wrap the last line in a span, add br or set fixed width to break exactly in that line.

Comment: @clickbait done I think. Thank you very much for clarifying the problem.